Why does Chrome reload components when pointing to an ID #?
For a ReactJs/NextJs APP (www.example.com for example), For Chrome browser, when I am located to some section of a page and then I enter www.example.com#sectionId, where sectionId is a section much lower than the one I am currently placed, I see that Chrome reloads the whole page and the elements like svg and styles are reloaded(in the network view in the developer tools) and Chrome for a moment shows me the section I want, but after a few microseconds it redirects me to the previous section as if it has memory to return me to the initial step, but when I do the same in Firefox it does not reload, it just moves to the desired section.
I can't find any reason why it has this behavior.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
